# Why does Android give me an "UnsatisfiedLinkError" when using QML?

Tags: android, qt, qml, archlinux

To develop my own Android Qt application I tried the HelloWorld application by Qt first before going into actual development. On "Desktop" the app works just fine but as soon as I switch to the "Android" kit I get following error:

```
07-22 20:25:50.387   250   797 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.qtproject.example.android/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity (has extras)} from uid 10007 on display 0
07-22 20:25:50.606   250   539 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2096:org.qtproject.example.android/u0a56 for activity org.qtproject.example.android/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
07-22 20:25:50.610   250   270 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(android.os.IBinder) from ActivityManagerService.java:6439 waiters=0 for 106ms
07-22 20:25:50.675  2096  2096 I art     : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-22 20:25:50.676  2096  2096 I art     : Late-enabling JIT
07-22 20:25:50.997  2096  2096 I art     : JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
07-22 20:25:51.557   250   270 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(android.app.IApplicationThread) from ActivityManagerService.java:6186 waiters=0 for 120ms
07-22 20:25:51.560   250   271 W art     : Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(android.app.IApplicationThread) from ActivityManagerService.java:6186 waiters=1 for 120ms
07-22 20:25:51.621   754   963 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa4072070
07-22 20:25:53.336  2096  2096 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
07-22 20:25:53.569  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x50810
07-22 20:25:53.570  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
07-22 20:25:53.616  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe5cf
07-22 20:25:53.616  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
07-22 20:25:53.642  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x32c74
07-22 20:25:53.643  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
07-22 20:25:53.689  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x3d982
07-22 20:25:53.689  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
07-22 20:25:53.770  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x4b73
07-22 20:25:53.770  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
07-22 20:25:53.808  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x9241
07-22 20:25:53.808  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
07-22 20:25:53.809  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libqtforandroid.so"
07-22 20:25:53.812  2096  2096 W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.android-1/lib/arm/libandroid.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x306
07-22 20:25:53.856  2096  2096 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-22 20:25:53.858  2096  2096 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-22 20:25:53.858  2096  2096 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.loadApplication(QtLoader.java:237)
07-22 20:25:53.858  2096  2096 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp(QtLoader.java:647)
07-22 20:25:53.858  2096  2096 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate(QtActivityLoader.java:181)
07-22 20:25:53.858  2096  2096 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:269)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-22 20:25:53.859  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-22 20:25:53.860  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-22 20:25:53.860  2096  2096 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-22 20:25:53.860  2096  2096 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-22 20:25:53.860  2096  2096 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-22 20:25:53.860  2096  2096 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-22 20:25:53.861  2096  2096 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "AAssetManager_fromJava" referenced by "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so"...
07-22 20:25:53.861  2096  2096 W System.err:    at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:332)
07-22 20:25:53.862  2096  2096 W System.err:    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1069)
07-22 20:25:53.862  2096  2096 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.loadQtLibraries(QtNative.java:171)
07-22 20:25:53.862  2096  2096 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:502)
07-22 20:25:53.862  2096  2096 W System.err:    ... 17 more
```

I am using ArchLinux and the android-qt5-armeabi-v7a package from the aur, which provides the Qt library for Android. The project uses Qt5.7 and the API level of my Android device is 23.

Comment: You could try using [Qt installers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) to install it, or [building Qt](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding) yourself.

Comment: That is exactly what the aur package does, it retrieves the source code of Qt everywhere and compiles it using the Android NDK.

Comment: Not correctly, apparently. :p

Comment: @Mitch I tried to compile Qt's Hello World application with the Qt-Libraries and QtCreator compiled by Qt itself (version 5.7 running on ArchLinux) and I encounter the exact same issue

Comment: @msrd0, hmm, weird. Which NDK revision are you guys using?

Comment: @Mitch I'm using r12_b (as far as I know this is the latest) from the AUR (I've reviewed the PKGBUILD this package simply downloads from Google and extracts the package)